# Shape parameters for finite and infinite variance in Burr distribution

Tags: distributions, variance, mean

Just like in Pareto distribution, we have 1 < alpha<2 for finite mean and finite variance. Is there any such range condition on shape parameters of Burr distribution as well? What is that range?

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia page on on the Burr type XII, it looks like having $1<ck<2$ should suffice. I'll try to come back and check more closely.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes I agree. But what is confusing is: using scipy my data fits burr with shape 5.9, 43969 and pareto with shape 1.2. Clearly here ck != alpha

Comment: The parameterization of the Burr XII on the Wikipedia page is different from the parameterization on scipy.stats.burr -- I expect that could account for the difference. You'd need constraints for that parameterization of the Burr.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes I checked. scipy gives burr 3 and wikipedia gives 12. Thanks. Can you provide a reference to study the mean of burr distribution or give a hint here to compute mean of burr distribution in some range x to y

Comment: @Glen_b Actually the way, I tried to compute the mean I do not get a closed form expression.

Comment: The expectation is given on the Wikipedia page I already mentioned.

Comment: You may find it helpful to use the identity $B(\alpha,\beta) = \int_0^\infty \!\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{(1+t)^{\alpha+\beta}}dt$ and then to consider a suitable change of variable, but this is really a new question.